# Create a slide counter per section

Tags: beamer, counters

Is there a way in beamer to have a counter of slides that resets with every section (in addition to the global counter that does not reset with sections)?

See below for a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
  \usebeamerfont{footline}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
  \hspace{1em}%
  [0/0]  % slide counter per section
  \hspace{1em}%
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber%
}

\section{Section 1}
\frame{Frame 1.1}  % Should display [1/3] in footer
\frame{Frame 1.2}  % Should display [2/3] in footer
\frame{Frame 1.3}  % Should display [3/3] in footer

\section{Section 2}
\frame{Frame 2.1}  % Should display [1/2] in footer
\frame{Frame 2.2}  % Should display [2/2] in footer

\end{document}
```

Comment: One difficullty I see is that there might be no easy way to know how many frames there are in one section. At least not when the section starts.

Comment: I would assume a similar solution to the total frame count would work though (I don’t know what that solution is unfortunately)

Comment: Oh, there is indeed: `\insertsectionendpage`. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\insertsectiontotalframes}{\the\numexpr\insertsectionendpage-\insertsectionstartpage+1\relax}
\newcommand{\insertsectioncurrentframe}{\the\numexpr\insertpagenumber-\insertsectionstartpage+1\relax}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}\insertsectioncurrentframe{} / \insertsectiontotalframes}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}{1/3} \end{frame}
\begin{frame}{2/3} \end{frame}
\begin{frame}{3/3} \end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}{1/2} \end{frame}
\begin{frame}{2/2} \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Luckily, `beamer` obviously already knows the frame number of the first and the last frame of the current section. With this knowledge, you can easily calculate the current frame number relative to the current section as well as the total number of frames of the current section.

PS: A look into `beamerbasenavigation.sty` reveals even more interesting `\insert...number` macros.